# JSF Dropdowns - Enforce non-defautl value for validation

Tags: validation, jsf, drop-down-menu, jsf-2, required

We have JSF dropdowns that use a default value of "Select One..", but we do not want our JSF validator to accept this as an accpetable value on save.

so beyond/or in place of Required="true", is there any way to do this?

example values:

```
"select one.."
"cat"
"dog"
```

Only "cat" or "dog" should pass validation.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `required="true"`? That's in fact the only valid solution. If it's actually the default message which is bothering you, then it may be good to know that there are ways to customize this.

Comment: Hey Balus. We are using required ="true", and the problem is that we don't get a message when users save a value of "select one".  

We are trying to augment that with an additional condition that says "this value of "XX" is not acceptable"

What if I set the value(not displayed) to an empty string, would that fail the required validation?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have set "Select one..." as *both* the label and value. In order to trigger the requireness validator, the value has to be `null`. You need to set "Select one..." as **label** and `null` as **value**.

So in view:

```
<f:selectItem itemValue="null" itemLabel="Select one..." />
```

or in model:

```
new SelectItem(null, "Select one...");
```

Comment: Perfect. So to my commetn earlier though, *it must be null, and not "" to fail validation?*  Seems like an empty string should be just as reasonable to fail as a null string.

Comment: yEP,  a string of "" for the value will fail validation as well. Awesome.